# how to ensure console object's existence as window object's property in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, browser, coffeescript

I use coffee code below to check and ensure console object's existence under window object for lower IE browser's compatibility.

```
window.console = window.console ? {}
```

coffee script transpiler generate code like below

```
window.console = (_ref = window.console ) != null ? _ref : {};
```

I don't think code above is right. If I write javascript directly, it will be like this:

```
if(window.console) window.console = {};
```

or

```
if (typeof console === "undefined" || console === null) {
  console = {};
}
```

How to do it correctly in coffeescript?

Answer (score 2):

Use the existential operator `?=` instead of `?`:

```
window.console ?= {}
```

It [compiles](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3awindow.console%20?=%20%7B%7D) to

```
if (window.console == null) {
    window.console = {};
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's right. the generated code does not check `typeof console === "undefined"`

Comment: @HenryLeu There's no need to check for `typeof === "undefined"`. Generally property look-ups don't throw any error. Second, `a == null` is equivalent to `a === null || a === void 0` (`void 0` is the undefined value). `window.console == null` will thus be true if console is either not defined, or `null` (you're mainly interested in the first case, but the second case doesn't hurt).

Answer (score 0):

[You can use backticks to execute Javascript in coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%60window.console%20%3D%20window.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%60):

```
`window.console = window.console || {}`
```

Comment: Is there a way to go in native coffeescript code? frankly, I feel not confortable to mix them together

Comment: @HenryLeu Then you can use `window.console = window.console ? {}` to achieve the same